# Buscador Autocompletar AngularJS + SQL SERVER no muestra resultados

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, autocompletar, buscador

*Estoy realizando un buscador por medio de una BD en SQL Server y AngularJS donde al momento de escribir te va sugeriendo los resultados (Tipo Google)*

**El problema es que no me muestra los resultados sugeridos lo estoy realizando de la siguiente forma:**

```js
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$con = conexion();


if($_GET['value'] != ""){
$sql="SELECT id_persona,nombre_completo,sexo, calle_no FROM PERSONAS where nombre_completo LIKE '".$_GET['value']."%'";
 $res=sqlsrv_query($con,$sql);

    $array = array();


    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    }


    echo json_encode($array);
}

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cargar">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script>

 var appCargar = angular.module('cargar', []);

 appCargar.controller('usuariosController', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.cargausuarios = function(){
   $http({url: "json.php", 
   method: "GET",
   params: {value: $scope.usuario}
   }).then(function(usuarios) {$scope.usuarios = usuarios;});
  }
  //Cuando eliges un usuario lo reemplaza en el campo de texto
  $scope.cambiausuario = function(usuario){
   $scope.usuario = usuario;
   $scope.usuarios = null;
  }
  
 });

 </script> 
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="usuariosController">
    <input ng-model="usuario" ng-change="cargausuarios()" placeholder="Buscar usuario" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
            <a ng-click="cambiausuario(usuario.nombre_completo)">
                {{ usuario.nombre_completo }}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Cuando inspecciono los elementos en el google Chrome si me trae el JSON, pero en  {{ usuario.nombre_completo }} no me muestra nada...**

*Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda..*

Comment: Intenta  `$scope.usuarios = usuarios.data;` en el metodo `then`  dinos que pasa.

Comment: @Einer si quedó gracias, pero ahora me sale este error: angular.js:14525 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]... me podrías asesorar para mejorarlo por favor.

Comment: Cual fue el error?

Comment: @Einer este: angular.js:14525 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=usuario%20in%20usuarios&p1=string%3A%3C&p2=%3C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El response del `$http` esta en la propiedad `data`. Y el error `[ngRepeat:dupes]` pudiera ser que la repuesta del servidor sea un texto plano y no un objeto json parseado. Si ese es tu caso utiliza `JSON.parse` para convertirlo a un objeto JSON:

```
$http({url: "json.php", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {value: $scope.usuario}
}).then(function(usuarios) {
    $scope.usuarios = JSON.parse(usuarios.data);
});
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho!! analizaré esto!! gracias!!